# Best Drawing approach

Tags: c++, bitmap, drawing, wxwidgets

I have developed an application in wxWidgets in which I am using bitmap for drawing. So First time when my application launches, it reads coordinates from file and draw lines accordingly. The application also receives UDP packets from network, UDP packets also contain some x y coordinates information which has to be drawn on the screen, so when the packet are received I redraw the bitmap image, and display on screen, I also need to refresh the bitmap on mouse move event because on mouse move there is some new drawing which I have to draw on screen.

All this increases the operational cost and slows down my GUI. So kindly suggest me some alternative drawing approach which you think might be efficient in this situation.

I have searched out on Google and got the option of OpenGL, but due to time shortage I don't want to use openGL, because I haven't any experience of OpenGL.

Comment: You had 1337 points. I don't like that. Upvoted :P

Comment: Can't you save an instance of bitmap in memory and only draw new information to it, without redrawing the whole thing? And stretch-blit the bitmap to screen...

Comment: @freerider, I am drawing some specific information on memory, but when I have to remove the existing lines from bitmap and draw new lines, in this situation I have to redraw the whole bitmap.

Comment: @Siddiqui Can't you do a bitmap-cache that contains images of the lines up to several points in time. Then you only have to combine a couples of bitmaps (just use XOR, if the background is WHITE) and draw the remaining lines to the result.

Comment: @freerider, Suppose I have a main bitmap (the background of GUI) and a polygon XOR'ed with main bitmap, and now a packet is received from the network which has updated coordinates of the polygon, so how can I update the polygon without redrawing main bitmap?

Comment: @Siddiqui save the first polygon coordinates, draw the polygon. when getting the updated coordinates, erase only the first polygon in the bitmap, redraw the new polygon. I other words: remove and paint only the needed part of the image...

Comment: @freerider, once I have XOR'ed the polygon with the main bitmap, how can I erase it?

Comment: @Siddiqui set the color to background where the polygon is.

Comment: @freerider, its multicolored background image (different elements have different colour representation).

Comment: >once I have XOR'ed the polygon with the main bitmap, how can I erase it?

Just XOR it again! (what puzzles me is how it might look after the First XOR as it is in color...)

Comment: Let me get this straight: you have a bitmap which must be filled with shapes that you either draw with the mouse or get them from network. After a time there are to many shapes that must be redrawn and this bogs down the GUI. Can you optimize by calculating which shapes will not change and just draw them to a second bitmap that serves as a start-buffer for new drawing of new shapes?

Comment: @freerider, thanks for your valuable suggestion. This approach will be efficient somehow,for sure, but can you suggest me some more other ways to achieve this even more efficiently??

Comment: Just some basics rules of thumb of games programming: maximize the through-output of data, search for drawing-functions that can draw several shapes at once. Minimize the calculation at runtime: if you can have several caches for already drawn shapes, use it. There are multiple game-development tutorials on the net that can be useful. At last: use another API that can handle hardware-acceleration and have better performance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if your problem is that your GUI is unresponsive to user input because the application is busy redrawing the display.  There are a couple of general solutions to this kind of problem.

1. Draw the bitmap in memory using a worker thread.  While this is going on the main thread can continue to interact with the user.  Once the bitmap has been redrawn, the worker thread signals the main thread, and the main thread then copied the completed bitmap to the screen - which is extremely fast.
2. Use the main thread to draw the bitmap directly to the screen, but sprinkle the drawing code with calls to wxApp::Yield().  This will allow the GUI to remain responsive to the user during a lengthy drawing process.

Option 1 is the 'best', especially when running on multicore machines, but it is a challenge to keep the two threads synchronized and prevent contention between them, unless you have significant experience with multithreading design.  Option 2 is much simpler, though you still have to be careful that the user interaction doesn't start another drawing process before the first is finished.

Comment: This won't change anything, "drawing to memory" is a non sense (where would you draw otherwise?). Using 2 threads, one for drawing and one for executional code is not that a bad ides but you must link those two together (ie. no calculations when drawing and no drawing when calculating which means low benefices).

OP wants a simple (or not too complicated) solution to his problem an the solution is "Don't update GUI every frame because that takes time". Like it or not :-)

Answer (score 0):

Save off the data to draw instead of always refreshing the bitmap and have the main loop make refreshes of the bitmap from time to time.

This way you can make the program never hog down. The backside is of course that the reactivity will be lower (ie. when data comes, it won't be seen on screen for another 20 milliseconds instead of right away).